# P2 repositories aggregator

Tags: eclipse, aggregate, p2

we have several internal p2 repositories. Each repository has many versions of different features. We need to have an external update site for our clients. We would like to aggregate only specific versions of specific features. Would is a good way/tool to "aggregate" them?

For example we have a p2 repository `repo1` with feature `feature1` with versions `1.0.0`, `2.0.0`, `3.0.0` and another p2 repository `repo2` with feature `feature2` with versions `1.0.0` and `2.0.0`.
We would like to aggregate versions `1.0.0` and `3.0.0` of `feature1` and version `2.0.0` of `feature2`:

```
feature1
  1.0.0
  3.0.0
feature2
  2.0.0
```

<strike>Currently we are looking at [b3](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_b3/aggregator/manual) and [Nexus Pro](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus-professional.html). But maybe there is something better?</strike>

[b3](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_b3/aggregator/manual) allows only aggregating range of features and not specific versions.
[Nexus Pro](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus-professional.html) is more like proxy or "magic box". We want to have a separate physical copy (mirrored one) of p2 repository.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`p2.mirror`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Ant_Tasks) can aggregate specified features and create a p2 repository. It is possible to configure it to download only required bundles too.

Here is an example which aggregates two versions of a feature:

```
<p2.mirror>
  <repository location="${repositoryPath}" name="My External p2 Repository" append="false" />
  <source>
    <repository location="http://repository:8081/p2/project1" />
    <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6" />
    <repository location="http://repository:8081/p2/project2" />
  </source>
  <iu id="dk.sorokin.maksim.feature.feature.group" version="0.0.5.201012071808" />
  <iu id="dk.sorokin.maksim.feature.feature.group" version="2.0.0.201012071540" />
  <slicingoptions followStrict="true" />
</p2.mirror>
```

Moreover, afterwards it is possible to run a `eclipse.publish.featuresAndBundles` task to categorize created repository.

Answer (score 4):

P2 has [composite repository](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_%28new%29) concept that should match what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point here. However, at the moment we find b3 better than. It has a nice ui. And also it can additionally verify produced repository.