# Mirror Eclipse P2 with dependencies ... how?

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, p2, mirror

We would like to mirror an Eclipse update site completely, so that also all dependencies are mirrored completely.

At the moment we are creating a mirror of an update site, so that we can use this mirror also in a network, which has no access to the internet.

When we want to download and install some plugins of this mirrored update site, we get the error that Eclipse can not resolve all dependencies, because these dependencies are on a different repository in the internet.

Is there any possibility to create the mirror with Ant, so that also all dependencies are downloaded automatic?

Comment: Where would the algorithm know which repositories are needed?

Comment: How does eclipse know?  It does, so there must be a solution, and you'd think that solution would be built into eclipse!  PS, I'd really like an answer to this question as well!  We develop in a completely offline environment and most eclipse plugins neglect to create archive builds or the archives get very out of date.

Answer (score 0):

**The quick workaround** is to also mirror all of the other repositories. You can know which ones by looking into Eclipse and see what is listed when you would do a normal installation. For example, a stock eclipse (I am looking at 2019-03 here) will contain the following repositories:

- 2019-03 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-03
- The Eclipse Project Updates - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.11

In order to install from the first repo you might need dependencies from the second repo and hence you need to mirror them both.

If you want to dive in and create a aggregated/combined repo you can use the p2.mirror tool [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378112/p2-repositories-aggregator).

Answer (score -1):

How are you doing the mirroring?
To mirror a whole updatesite you can do:

```
path\to\eclipse.exe -noSplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -source {original location} -destination {destinationOfNewRepo}
```

Of course these commands are made for local repositories. Then upload them to the updatesite.
Hope it helps

Comment: Doing standard mirroring like that doesn't prevent external resources to be missing once installing offline from downloaded/mirrored site.